# Small site / online database

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have to develop a small website and I wanted to understand which language to use.
The main purpose of this site is to access various tables, for example customer table, orders, warehouse, etc. by people with login / password.
Each user must be part of a group with specific functionalities (for example, they can access only for reading or make insertions / changes and no deletions, others only administration, etc.).
I have good knowledge of PHP and long ago I did something similar accessing 4 tables using CodeIgniter and MySQL.

I could proceed with CodeIgniter as the problem is basically identical, but I wanted to take one more step and, after analyzing various types of PHP and CMS frameworks, I deduced that the best solution is to switch to OctoberCMS (which is based however on the Laravel framework).
Initially I had opted to switch to the use of Laravel (it is more advanced than CodeIgniter) but with OctoberCMS theoretically I save a good part of work (long and laborious for the various pages and controls) while still leaving me a complete customization of the contents and the possibility of also inserting code native php for particular functions.
I prefer to be the owner of the data and that they are not hosted by third parties also because I already have some tables on a MySQL database and I would like to access them too.

Do any of you know OctoberCMS to suggest me if it could be the right solution?
Or is it better to change to something else? 
I have already checked in the forum but it seems to be no trace of this problem.
I also have knowledge of Microsoft Access and it would be nice to develop it with this tool since with a few clicks you can do many things ... but there is a problem, it cannot be put online (I am not only referring to tables but also to forms and reports).
What I am looking for, could be a tool similar to Microsoft Access (access to tables and masks to insert data and display table lists) but that can be used on the Internet to share and simultaneous use from people around the world.
In my opinion it is better not to use a Remote Desktop / Terminal Server solution, it doesn't seem serious or functional.

Thank you for the help.
Davide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

October CMS is perfect for this (disclaimer: I'm one of its maintainers). It has a robust roles / permissions system, is highly extendable, based on Laravel, and extremely easy to get started quickly with. Check out the builder plugin to kickstart your development process (it's a visual scaffolding tool to build your own plugins). It's also extremely easy to use October without the frontend "cms" module entirely and just use the backend functionality for custom Web applications.

Feel free to join the discord to ask more specific questions: https://octobercms.com/support

Comment: Thanks for the edit Glorfindel, was going to add that myself.